# WebBrowser ActiveElement vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo un bug cuando quiero insertar un texto con más de 2000 caracteres desde un `TextArea`, si es menor a esa cantidad de caracteres; inserta el texto sin problemas.

El `ActiveElement` me retorna "Nothing" si supero esa cantidad, sino me devuelve `system.windows.Forms.HtmlElements`.

```
Friend WithEvents AxWebBrowser1 As New WebBrowser

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
    Me.AxWebBrowser1 = New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    Me.ContextMenuStrip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(Me.components)
    Me.ListToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
    Me.List1ToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
    Me.ContextMenuStrip1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()



Sub RecoverIndexValues(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles AxWebBrowser1.Navigating
    Dim doc1 As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument = Me.AxWebBrowser1.Document
    'Guardar indices
    Dim blnSaveWithRule As Boolean = False

    Trace.WriteLineIf(ZTrace.IsVerbose, "proc RecoverIndexValues.")

    'Valido que no haya ninguna regla pendiente de ejecucion
    If Not IsNothing(doc1) AndAlso doc1.ActiveElement Is Nothing Then
        Dim RuleElement As HtmlElement = doc1.GetElementById("hdnRuleId")
        If (Not IsNothing(RuleElement)) Then
            If (String.Compare(RuleElement.Name, String.Empty)) Then
                Dim RuleValue As String = RuleElement.Name
                RuleElement.Name = String.Empty

                RuleValue = RuleValue.Remove(0, "zamba_rule_".Length)

                If String.Compare(RuleValue.ToLower(), "cancel") = 0 Then
                    RaiseEvent CancelChildRules(True)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Exit Sub


 Public Sub saveValues(ByVal doc1 As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument, ByVal        closeBrowser As Boolean, ByVal canedit As Boolean)
    If IsNothing(doc1) Then
        doc1 = Me.AxWebBrowser1.Document
    End If
```

Comment: Sería bueno que revises el código que has adjuntado pues hay errores en tiempo de compilación, para así te puedan apoyar mejor con la respuesta, además separes el designer del codebehind.

Comment: ¿La pagina que tomas, la puedes editar o es ajena a ti?

Comment: Buenas,al final lo pude resolver.El error estaba en el codigo HTML,al Form le faltaba la linea method="POST",se la agrege y funciona sin problemas...gracias!

Comment: @Andromeda, si esa es la solución, haz del comentario la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Al final lo pude resolver.

El error estaba en el codigo HTML, al form le faltaba la linea

```
method="POST"
```

Se la agregué y funciona sin problemas